# Excel - DateTime text to Column

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have multiple rows of datetime data.
For eg:

```
1/10/2014 10:10
2/3/2015 00:03
12/3/2015 12:03
4/3/2015 08:03
2/3/2015 14:03
6/3/2015 22:03
29/03/15 08:03:40
20/03/15 19:03:25
```

The first 6 rows seems to have been recognized as DateTime by Excel, whereas the 7th and 8th row seem to be in text format.

I'm not able to perform any datetime calculations on it.

I tried Text to Column, but that doesn't give me the option to keep the Date and Time together.

Please advise.

Comment: seems to be working for me..

Comment: I think this has to do with the localization settings on your computer.  If you go to control panel -> Region and Language, what is it set at?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Text to Columns tool and let the data be split into two columns. In step 3 define the date order as DMY (the order that the source data is in).

Then create a new column where you add the Date and time to get everything back into one column again. Copy, paste values, delete individual date and time columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the localization on your PC (or don't want to because it will mess up other things), you can always import this as text and then coerce the data into a date/time based on the known format.  I don't know of any date parse function in Excel, so you may have to do it the brute force way:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,2)+2000,MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))
```

Because you have multiple formats on your input, you may actually be forced into this.  If you want it to work universally on all dates, a UDF would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Excel parsed your date as:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm
```

as Excel Default. You can possibly overwrite that by trying what Teylyn have posted.

For example your 1st date: `1/10/2014 10:10` is interpreted as *January 10, 2014* and not *October 1, 2014*.

What you need to do is identify and standardized your date format first.
Once you've done that, we can help you how to move forward in getting your dates correctly on the cells.